# How do I know what server name or web address was set on Nginx

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, ubuntu, nginx

I am trying to setup LEMP (Linux, Nginx, MySQL, PHP) stack on my PC to use with Wordpress. 
I follow the instructions on [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-in-ubuntu-16-04) website. I see that the folder of wordpress in `www` folder was successfully extracted.

I can also verify that `Nginx` is running. However, I don't know how to get the wordpress index.php page on the browser.

[image]

On windows, I simply go to the browser and type `localhost/webprojectfoldername` or `127.0.0.1/webprojectfoldername`

However, when I try to access the `index.php` of wordpress via `localhost`, I get the Apache page.

[image]

I would like to use `Nginx` as server but not `Apache`. I guess at this point, I don't know what **servername** or **ipaddress** to put on the browser to get to `Nginx`'s page or `Wordpress`'s `index.php`

I don't know how to identify the servername that was setup. On Windows, I simply use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

Any thoughts on how I identify it on Ubuntu?

I'd appreciate any help.

Thank you.

*** EDIT (Added Screenshot of Nginx configuration) ****

[image]

Comment: Check your nginx config, which is usually in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`

Comment: Argh! It is text! You can copy/paste text. Don't show us pictures of text.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either:

## nginx is listening on a different port

By default, HTTP works over port 80, but when you connect to that port you are reaching Apache.

You need to find the port nginx is listening on (from the article you link to: `listen 80 default_server;` shows `80` but lets say it was `81`) and connect to that instead: http://localhost:81/`

## nginx and apache are trying to listen on the same port and apache won

You need to turn off Apache (and possibly restart nginx).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree. It appears that apache wins in using port 80. I tried your suggestion of turning off apache using this command: `systemctl stop apache2.service` Then I restarted the nginx using this command: `sudo systemctl restart nginx` For some reason, when I put `localhost` on the browser, it still returns with apache page. I'll add the screenshot of `nginx`'s configuration for additional details.

Comment: Then either (1) You're loading the Apache page from the browser cache and not hitting the server at all or (2) nginx is configured to use the same directory as Apache as its root directory